# Estimate market risk premium?

Tags: market-data, factor-models, market, stylized-facts

There are uncountably many factor models to estimate stock returns, such as CAPM, Fama-French, Carhart-Momentum, APT etc.

Which models can estimate the market (index) return?

I found only three models: [Cay](http://www.econ.nyu.edu/user/ludvigsons/eqprem1.pdf), [Dividends](https://www0.gsb.columbia.edu/faculty/gbekaert/stockreturn.pdf) and [Average Correlation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304405X10000437).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, those are probably the variables that predict the better the stock market return. However, the OOS evidence is usually weak.

Goyal & Welch provide a good summary on predictors: http://rfs.oxfordjournals.org/content/21/4/1455.abstract